# Asp.Net MVC Razor Foreach throws null Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach

My code :

```
 @if (Model.ClientTypes != null)
 {
  foreach (var clientType in Model.ClientTypes)
  {
     @:blabla :)
  }
 }
```

ClientTypes collection is a list and it´s not null, there are 5 elements in ClientTypes, razor engine enters in loop and after looping all 4 elements at the end  throws null exception :(

what is wrong ?

[image]

Comment: So on the 5th element it throws null exception ?

Comment: Have you checked, if all properties of your model are *not null*?

Comment: but there is no code where David accessing some ClientType property .. so clientType could be null

Comment: As you are not accessing any property of clientType, it would not throw any null exception to u. Or do you mind post your exact code in @:blabla :)?

Comment: I am not accessing any property that's why i wrote "blabla ", very strange problem

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this same problem and discovered that the error was actually lying to me.  The error wasn't on the foreach loop, it was on the line *following* the foreach loop.  So my recommendation is to comment out anything that could be null immediately following the foreach loop and then uncomment one at a time until you find the culprit.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much, I had a null object 40 lines below the loop !

Comment: Me too! That's really strange

Comment: Does anyone know what causes this?